# docker + nginx + ssl failed in development environment

Tags: docker, nginx

I have some problems with running docker container with nginx and self signed ssl certificate.
Primarily I am using my local setup to check app in docker containers before uploading to production. So configuration is almost the same as in production through docker.
Unfortunately I get a HSTS error.

Is there any good practice to have web development environment or local test setup that can be checked without any problems?

My setup:

- angular app
- node js backend
- nginx with redirection for backend to same host

Comment: There are a lot of ways to reach your goal! There is no "best way". We need more info about what are you doing. With this info maybe we can provide better answers.

Do you use a CI-Server (like Jenkins)? I guess this is a good starting point to think about.

Comment: First I would like to test this locally. Of course I can have different nginx config without ssl. But I'm looking for something that allow me run same config that will be as close as possible to production.